# Why is my USB not detected as a bootable disk at startup

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, uefi

I installed a multiboot iso on the second partition of my flash drive. However, whenever I startup my PC, I never get prompted to boot from USB. It doesn't show up when I go into BIOS and manually choose a drive to boot off of.

Is there a reason for this? And how can I fix it. It seems like there is a /boot/grub/x86_64-efi folder on my flash drive at least so I don't know why this is all happening.

Thank you.

Comment: Set a boot flag (boot,esp) for the EFI partition with GParted as shown in the presentation of my answer -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/883544/how-can-i-create-an-efi-partition-on-my-usb-drive/883551#883551 to your other question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/883544/how-can-i-create-an-efi-partition-on-my-usb-drive from today. Also make sure that the EFI partition / folder contains everything that is needed to boot properly. :)

Comment: How did you install the "multiboot iso?" (Did you use `dd`, copy files manually, use some dedicated tool, etc.?) Also, what specific "multiboot iso" was this -- an Ubuntu installation image? Finally, what type of firmware are you using (BIOS vs. EFI)? (Your question includes the "UEFI" tag, so that implies the latter, but it's best to be extremely clear about this detail, since it's so critical.)

Comment: I used Unetbootin to install a multiboot ISO file. And it's EFI firmware.