# Failing to install bootloader to USB

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, system-installation, live-usb

I am trying to **install** Ubuntu 16.04 to my USB-Stick. I have followed the guide in the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170454/can-i-install-ubuntu-to-my-32-gb-usb-pen-drive) (however, I am using another usb containing the installation files instead of a CD). Everything works fine, just that the bootloader does not get installed on the usb although I have chosen the same device.

The destination usb is `/dev/sdd`. There is only one partition `/dev/sdd1` which I format to `ext4` during the installation.

[image]

*(example picture, not taken from my computer)*

In the partitioning window I chose `/dev/sdd1` as target. For *Device for the boot loader installation* at the bottom I chose `/dev/sdd`, as mentioned in the linked guide.

After the installation completed I restarted my laptop and went into the BIOS. Under boot options I saw:

```
UEFI BOOT:
     - ubuntu
     - Windows Boot Manager
```

Choosing *ubuntu* makes the laptop boot from the USB and the OS is running.
However, even when I remove my USB-Stick, *ubuntu* is still a boot option. If I choose it now, I get a command line:

```
Minimal BASH-like line editiing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions. 

grub> _
```

So the boot loader has been installed to the main disk instead of the USB, although I have chosen the correct location in the setup. The fact that my main PC without an Ubuntu bootloader cannot boot from the USB supports my assumption.

How can I install Ubuntu *including* the bootloader to my USB, so that I can use it on any computer which supports booting from USB?

Comment: Is this PC booting using BIOS or UEFI?

Comment: It is most probably booting using UEFI, Since it can find the minimal files for booting as well as there is an option even if the pendrive is removed.

Comment: @Aditya yes I think it is using UEFI. Is that wrong?

Comment: In this case, make 2 partitions on the pendrive: /dev/sdd1: EFI Partition (use link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/883544/how-can-i-create-an-efi-partition-on-my-usb-drive) and another /dev/sdd2: ext4 for "/". Now during Installaiton, select the boot loader device as "/dev/sdd" and you should be fine.

Comment: Do you want to preserve your current installation?

Comment: @Aditya No I do not want to preserve it. I will now try what you said in the comment before.

Comment: @Aditya How big should the EFI partition be?

Comment: Also, which model is your PC?

Comment: @Aditya x64 if that's what you mean

Comment: For Some PC's, all you may have to do is make a FAT32 partition in addition to the ext4 one and name it 'efi'. Inside, make a folder: "EFI". Inside this folder, copy the folder "EFI/ubuntu" inside the efi partition of your main HDD (Just the "ubuntu" folder). Just in case you do not want to waste time.

Comment: an EFI partition should be ~100MB or so depending on how many OS's you are installing. The efi files take usually about ~40MB of disk space.

Comment: @Aditya Adding the EFI partition did not help unfortunately :(

Comment: How did you add the EFI Partition? By adding a FAT32 partition or by following the other answer?

Comment: Also, after adding an EFI Partition to your USB, and successfully booting from it, you have to delete the "/EFI/ubuntu" folder in your main HDD`s efi partition (Make a copy of it first)

Comment: @Aditya I made it using mkusb now. Thanks for your help!